# Find multiple max dates in one query

Tags: sql-server, select, max, aggregate-functions

I have a data set where I'm trying to find the following:
If statusid = 113917, then I want to find the max date and call it "startstatusdate."  If statusid = 49938, then I to find the max date and call it "endstatusdate."

```
 declare @t table(practid int, statusid int, statusdate date)

 insert into @t values (1, 113917, '2018-03-01'),
                        (1, 113917, '2018-04-01'),
                        (1, 113917, '2018-05-01'),
                        (1, 49938, '2018-06-01'),
                        (2, 113917, '2018-03-15'),
                        (2, 113917, '2018-03-18'),
                        (2, 49938, '2018-04-22')
```

I want a result like this:

```
    practid           startstatusdate     endstatusdate
      1                  2018-03-01          2018-06-01
      2                  2018-03-15          2018-04-22
```

I'm able to create this using two temp tables, one that gets the max startstatusdate and another that gets the max endstatusdate, and then joining those tables.  But I'd like to do this in one query.

I was trying something like this:

```
    Select practid,
           (select max(statusdate)
            from Table A
            where statusid = 113917) as startstatusdate,
           (select max(statusdate)
            from Table A
            where statusid = 49938) as endstatusdate
    from Table A
    group by practid
```

Comment: You can do this with a [CASE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `case` expressions to take only the values from the relevant statuses:

```
SELECT   practid,
         MAX(CASE statusid WHEN 113917 THEN statusdate END) AS startstatusdate,
         MAX(CASE statusid WHEN 49938 THEN statusdate END) AS endstatusdate
FROM     table_a
GROUP BY practid
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Seems simple enough that I should have thought of this on my own.

Answer (score 2):

What @JNevill said is correct, this is a simple CASE statement.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(PRACTID INT, STATUSID INT, STATUSDATE DATE)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1, 113917, '2018-03-01'),
                        (1, 113917, '2018-04-01'),
                        (1, 113917, '2018-05-01'),
                        (1, 49938, '2018-06-01'),
                        (2, 113917, '2018-03-15'),
                        (2, 113917, '2018-03-18'),
                        (2, 49938, '2018-04-22')  

SELECT PRACTID,
    MIN(CASE STATUSID WHEN 113917 THEN STATUSDATE END) AS STARTSTATUSDATE,
    MAX(CASE STATUSID WHEN 49938 THEN STATUSDATE END) AS ENDSTATUSDATE
FROM @T
GROUP BY PRACTID
```

**NOTE**: (Based on your desired results) It looks like you want to use `MIN` for the `startstatusdate`, this should apply your desired results to your declared table `@t`